# Eclipse 4 - add part to SashForm

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

If you are too lazy to read all this, generally the question is: how to pass `Composite` parent to an existing part assuming that these parts are created by Eclipse, not manually.

I'm developing an Eclipse 4 plugin. I have different parts (views) in separate classes which communicate via events. Everything was fine and separated until I had to implement a `SashForm` containing 2 the parts. I've seen some examples but they mostly show simple usages of `SashForm`. 
What I want is to remain this modularity with all the dependency injection and auto events receiving (via annotations).
But I cannot figure out how to do this. 
My best attempt was to use `IEclipseContext` like this:

```
@Inject
private EventPool eventPool;

@Inject
private EventBroker eventBroker;

@Inject
private CMTreeContentProvider contentProvider;

@Inject
private LoginService loginService;

@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite shell) {
    SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    form.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    renderCMTree(form);
    renderProjects(form);
}

private void renderCMTree(SashForm form) {
    Composite child = new Composite(form, SWT.NONE);
    child.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    IEclipseContext context = EclipseContextFactory.create();
    context.set(Composite.class, child);
    context.set(EventPool.class, eventPool);
    context.set(EventBroker.class, eventBroker);
    context.set(CMTreeContentProvider.class, contentProvider);
    ContextInjectionFactory.make(CMTreeView.class, context);
    context.dispose();
}

private void renderProjects(SashForm form) {
    Composite child = new Composite(form, SWT.NONE);
    child.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    IEclipseContext context = EclipseContextFactory.create();
    context.set(Composite.class, child);
    context.set(EventPool.class, eventPool);
    context.set(EventBroker.class, eventBroker);
    ContextInjectionFactory.make(CMTicketView.class, context);
    context.dispose();
}
```

As you can see, I have to manually inject all the dependencies through the context. And with this approach, the event consuming doesn't work inside `CMTreeView` and `CMTicketView` (but ok, I subscribe to events manually). I could live with this but maybe there is a better way to remain the modularity? I really don't want this class to be 2000+ rows long.

Comment: Why aren't you using a 'Part Sash Container' in the Application.e4xmi to contain the two parts?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the comment. I tried to use it but could not make it work. All the examples I've seen about `PartSashContainer` seem to use RCP model, but I develop a plugin. Is it possible to add `PartSashContainer ` as a view to make it accessible through Window -> Show view?

Comment: I add views to the Model Fragment with Feautre Name 'descriptors'. Can I add PartSashContainer in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

You should really try and use something like 'Part Sash Container' in the Application.e4xmi to contain the parts.

If you have to use `ContextInjectionFactory.make` to create something you can use the form which uses two `IEclipseContext` parameters to pass in the main context plus a secondary context containing just your values:

```
@Inject
IEclipseContext context; // injected existing context


IEclipseContext staticContext = EclipseContextUtil.createContext();

// Only need to put your own values in staticContext
staticContext.set(Composite.class, child);

// Pass in both contexts to make
ContextInjectionFactory.make(CMTreeView.class, context, staticContext);
```

Both contexts will be used to look up values needed by injection of `CMTreeView`.

Note: You should be using `IEventBroker` **not** `EventBroker` which is an **internal** class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't have an Application.e4xmi file since I don't develop an RCP application but a plugin, so I just have Model Fragments. Guess I'll better remove the 'eclipse-rcp' tag from my post. I'll definitely give it a try though because I really like this e4 style of injection and single responsibility.

Comment: You may still be able to use part sash container in a fragment depending on the design of the main application.e4xmi. The rest of the answer does not depend on using part sash container.